Is precision the same when comparing decimal values with Decimal.Compare and the == operator in C#?
I’m working with decimal values in C# and have encountered the need to precisely compare two decimal values. For this, I’ve considered two main methods of comparison: using Decimal.Compare and the equality (==) operator.
I would like to clarify if both the Decimal.Compare method and the == operator offer the same level of precision when comparing two decimal values. I’m curious about the circumstances, if any, under which the results of these two comparison methods might differ.
What I have tried:
I have attempted the following example code to compare two decimal values:
decimal value1 = 0.1m;
decimal value2 = 0.10m;

int compareResult = Decimal.Compare(value1, value2);
bool isEqualUsingCompare = (compareResult == 0);

bool isEqualUsingEqualityOperator = (value1 == value2);

In the code above, both using Decimal.Compare and the == operator seem to indicate that value1 and value2 are equal.
What I am expecting:
I am hoping to understand whether the above two methods are always reliable in all cases, especially if there are any edge cases where the results of comparing using these two methods might differ.

Does this answer your question? How to properly compare decimal values in C#?

No, I want to know the precision of Decimal.Compare and ==, rather than just comparing two decimal numbers.

For example, how many decimal places is it accurate to?

You can look in the source code. Both operator== and Compare call the same workhorse method DecCalc.VarDecCmp. Of, course, this alone is no contract.

You can look at the reference source (.NET Framework 4.6) for the Decimal struct. At lines 381 - 389 you can see:
// Compares two Decimal values, returning an integer that indicates their
// relationship.
//
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
[ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
public static int Compare(Decimal d1, Decimal d2) {
    return FCallCompare(ref d1, ref d2);
}

at lines 457 - 461:
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
public bool Equals(Decimal value)
{
    return FCallCompare(ref this, ref value) == 0;
}

and at lines 1162 - 1165:
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
public static bool operator ==(Decimal d1, Decimal d2) {
    return FCallCompare(ref d1, ref d2) == 0;
}

I.e., Decimal.Compare, Decimal.Equals, the operator == and all the other comparison operators as well as some methods like Min or Max not shown here rely on the same method FCallCompare and thus they all return consistent results.
You can use the .NET Source Browser for Decimal.cs for the .NET Core code instead. The method DecCalc.VarDecCmp is used for the comparison there, but otherwise: same consistent behavior (as expected).

Thanks for your answer, it's a great reference for me! I'm so busy with other things these days that I didn't reply in time, sorry.

Okay, but I don't have 15 reputations, so I can't site an upvote, but I have accepted your answer as the best. Thank you again!
